# 3 referenced files in your library will not upload to iCloud Photo Library error

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

> Select referenced files in your library and choose “Consolidate” from
>   the File menu to copy the original files into the library.

I get the following error messages when I try and sync my Photos Library on my mac with iCloud and then it just says 'Updating' indefinitely.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have selected all files and click Consolidate and it says 'No files to consolidate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by looking for all the filenames prefixed with "Copy - " and deleting them.