# How to find referenced files in Photo library

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photo-stream

In an attempt to transfer the photos off my iPhone to the Mac Photos app, I selected the "Import New Items" button and something seemed to process.

[image: screenshot of import process]

No photos got imported and I noticed a little cloud icon with an exclamation mark in it next to the iPhone in the sidebar. Once I selected that icon a dialog box came up, saying

> **Optimised Storage is Turned On**
>
> “iPhone (2)” is using iCloud Photos with optimised storage. Some photos and videos may not be available for import.

There was a "Learn More" button linking to [this Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT213272?cid=mc-ols-photos-article_ht213272-macos_ui-06232022) page.

[image: screenshot of Photos app with warning message]

I switched on iCloud Photos in the Photos App on macOS and immediately got this error message saying

> **4 referenced files in your library will not upload to iCloud Photos.**
>
> Select referenced files in your library and choose “Consolidate” from the File menu to copy the original files into the library.

[image: screenshot of Photos App settings with warning about referenced files]

I read somewhere that you have to un-tick the option that says "Optimise Mac Storage"

[image: screenshot of Photos App settings with disabled option "Optimise Mac Storage"]

Apparently, once you have done this, Photos should start uploading all of your photos and videos to iCloud. If there are any referenced files that are preventing the upload, you should see an error message with a list of the affected files. Supposedly, you can then use the "Consolidate" feature in the File menu to copy the original files into your Photos library so that they can be uploaded to iCloud.

However, in my case, once I select the "Ok" button in the screenshot above, I get a dialog box asking me to upgrade to a 2 TB iCloud+ storage. I don't want to shell out $14.99 just to find out which ones are the referenced photos.

[image: screenshot of dialog box showing upgrade options to iCloud+]

I also read [this Ask Different answer on a similar problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192728/3-referenced-files-in-your-library-will-not-upload-to-icloud-photo-library-error), but it didn't help me.

How do I know which ones these 4 referenced files are?

Comment: You're trying to import from your phone - you can either enable iCloud on both devices, or disable optimize storage on your phone so that the photos are downloaded to your phone (and can then be imported). The referenced photos on your Mac shouldn't be an issue either way.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't "referenced photos" mean that there are photos that are not in the Photos library (_Photos Library.photoslibrary_)?

Comment: yes, but that's not going to block you from enabling iCloud Photos - those photos just won't upload. If you don't want iCloud Photos for anything other than accessing your phone photos, then you don't have to worry about that. Like you said, they'll just be marked unable to upload.

Comment: Understand, but my goal (and question) was about finding out how to find referenced files in the Photo library, not about uploading or not uploading to iCloud. That appeared as a step towards finding out where referenced files are.

Comment: Well your goal was to get the optimized photos off your iPhone right? Those are different from referenced photos on macOS - sorry if I'm saying obvious things, but I'm trying to connect the first part of your question with the rest of the post

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Maybe that question developed into two issues: getting the photos off the iPhone and in an attempt to do that when I was presented with the fact that some photos are apparently referenced, how to figure out _which_ photos are referenced.

So, yes, my initial goal was to get the photos off the iPhone, and turning off iCloud sharing / syncing was the solution to that, but my problem / motivation for this question here was how to find which photos are referenced. Sorry, if that wasn't clear.